# Disk recovery: Error: -69461: Unable to get VEK info for an APFS Volume which is marked as encrypted in the IOKit Registry

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk, data-recovery

I'm trying to recover the contents of a backup disk.  It is an encrypted APFS volume with 3 containers.  The disk itself is probably okay - SMART reports no problems, and a quick 2 minute disk scan also reports no problems.

I tried running *diskutil repairVolume /dev/disk2*.  After quite a few minutes, I get the following error:

> Error: -69461: Unable to get VEK info for an APFS Volume which is marked as encrypted in the IOKit Registry

I tried running First Aid on one of the containers - that failed with:

`error: failed to enable crypto I/O mode for container /dev/rdisk3: Invalid argument`

And running *diskutil list* produces:

```
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +ERROR      disk3
                                 Physical Store disk2s1
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Passport #3 - Work   ⁩   ERROR      disk3s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Passport #3 - Person⁩    ERROR      disk3s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Passport #3 - Mac #3    ERROR      disk3s3
```

I even tried libfsapfs - no luck.

Any suggestions?